# while in MYSQL Script not SP or function

Tags: mysql, while-loop, syntax-error

I am trying to achieve loop functionality in MySQL script but below throws error.

```
set @sd = '2021-04-09';
set @ed = '2023-09-27';

WHILE @sd <= @ed DO
    SET @sd = DATE_ADD(@sd, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END while;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE @sd <= @ed DO
SET @sd = DATE_ADD(@sd, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END while' at line 1

Comment: Compound statements are only supported within `BEGIN`/`END` blocks in stored routines. I linked to a duplicate question -- that question was about `IF` conditional statements, but the same answer applies to `WHILE` loops, or any other of the compound statements. The linked answer includes a link to MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use MySQL loop / conditional control outside a SP. You Can't Do That™.